# Using LaPlace transform in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to use the Laplace transform to solve the following equation:

$ y''+16y=(t-3)u_3(t), y(0)=0, y'(0)=1 $

My solution:

So I see the left side of the equation works out to be:

$ s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+16(Y(s)) $

$ s^2 Y(s) - 0s -1 + 16Y(s) $

$ Y(s)[s^2+16] -1 $

I am not sure how to work with the right side of this equation, I know I have to move that $-1$ over to the other side so it becomes $ 1 $ and then divide both sides by $ s^2+16 $ to cancel it on the left side.

Looking for some help

Comment: There should be an entry in your Laplace transform table for $f(t-c) u(t-c)$. If not then you can compute it using the definition.

Comment: I do not see it in my table i have been given

Comment: Maybe of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684414/applying-two-laplace-properties-on-same-function, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783102/laplace-transform-with-heaviside-step-function/783104#783104, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232007/inverse-laplace-transformation-of-a-heaviside-function/1232024#1232024